# How to load MongoDB collection into Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, mongodb, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to create a data frame that contains MongoDB collection by the following:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient('Mongo URI')
db = client.My_Collection
collection = db.data

df = pd.DataFrame(list(collection.find()))
```

But it keeps waiting no matter how much I stay.. is there any solution to load them faster? The collection contains about 250000 documents.

Comment: Check this URL: https://www.mongodb.com/languages/python that should give an perspective on how to solve the issue. try to separate the activities until it works, like collection.find() and creating DF

Comment: I previously tried that, but nothing worked. @Bharath